# Check stock tickers in string against array

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following array which holds all US stock tickers, ordered by length:

```
$tickers = array('AAPL', 'AA', 'BRK.A', 'BRK.B', 'BAE', 'BA'); // etc...
```

I want to check a string for all possible matches. Tickers are written with or without a "$" concatenated to the front:

```
$string = "Check out $AAPL and BRK.A, BA and BAE.B - all going up!";
```

All tickers are to be labeled like: {TICKER:XX}. The expected output would be:

```
Check out {TICKER:AAPL} and {TICKER:BRK.A} and BAE.B - all going up!
```

So tickers should be checked against the $tickers array and matched both if they are followed by a space or a comma. Until now, I have been using the following:

```
preg_replace('/\$([a-zA-Z.]+)/', ' {TICKER:$1} ', $string);
```

so I didn't have to check against the $tickers array. It was assumed that all tickers started with "$", but this only appears to be the convention in about 80% of the cases. Hence, the need for an updated filter.

My question being: is there a simple way to adjust the regex to comply with the new requirement or do I need to write a new function, as I was planning first:

```
function match_tickers($string) {
  foreach ($tickers as $ticker) {
    // preg_replace with $
    // preg_replace without $
  }
}
```

Or can this be done in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the leading dollar sign optional, using `?` (zero or 1 matches).  Then you can check for legal trailing characters using the same technique.  A better way to go about it would be to `explode` your input string and check/replace each substring against the ticker collection, then reconstruct the input string.

```
 function match_tickers($string) {
      $aray = explode( " ", $string );
      foreach ($aray as $word) {
           // extract any ticker symbol
           $symbol = preg_replace( '/^\$?([A-Za-z]?\.?[A-Za-z])\W*$/', '$1', $word );
           if (in_array($symbol,$tickers)) { // symbol, replace it
               array_push( $replacements, preg_replace( '/^\$?([A-Za-z]?\.?[A-Za-z])(\W*)$/', '{TICKER:$1}$2', $word ) );
           }
           else { // not a symbol, just output it normally
               array_push( $replacements, $word );
           }
       }
       return implode( " ", $replacements );
 }
```

Comment: There may be more effective ways to use the functions (my native "language" is C#/.NET), but this should give you a general idea.  The reason that you do two replaces is that you first extract the ticker symbol, then replace it with the potential trailing characters.  I don't think you can do that in one step as the ticker symbols won't contain the varying punctuation that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think just a slight change to your regex should do the trick:

```
\$?([a-zA-Z.]+)
```

i added "?" in front of the "$", which means that it can appear 0 or 1 times

Comment: This doesn't check that the matched element is in the set of known tickers, i.e., it will also match `Check`, `and`, `all`, ...  It also doesn't take into account that the patterns match substrings now (since the leading $ is optional).

Comment: true enough. Like already mentioned in one of the answers, this should be used in combination with loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single foreach loop on your array to replace the ticker items in your string.

```
$tickers = array('AAPL', 'AA', 'BRK.A', 'BRK.B', 'BAE', 'BA');
$string = 'Check out $AAPL and BRK.A, BA and BAE.B - all going up!';

foreach ($tickers as $ticker) {
    $string = preg_replace('/(\$?)\b('.$ticker.')\b(?!\.[A-Z])/', '{TICKER:$2}', $string);
}

echo $string;
```

will output

> Check out {TICKER:AAPL} and {TICKER:BRK.A}, {TICKER:BA} and BAE.B -
>   all going up!

Comment: This will work but is very inefficient. It's an O(N*M), where N is number of words in the string and M is the number of ticker symbols.  A better algorithm would take advantage of O(1) array lookup in the tickers and have complexity O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `?` after the `$` sign will also accept words, i.e. 'out'

preg_replace accepts array as a pattern, so if you change your $tickers array to:
`$tickers = array('/AAPL/', '/AA/', '/BRK.A/', '/BRK.B/', '/BAE/', '/BA/');`

then this should do the trick:
`preg_replace($tickers, ' {TICKER:$1} ', $string);`

This is according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: `No one wants to buy an {TICKER:aa}rdvark as a pet.`